# Explanation about Direct Mapping to convert Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: sparql, rdf, etl, owl, ontology

One of the standards from W3C for RDB2RDF is [Direct Mapping](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/). I [heard](https://vimeo.com/66718408#t=15m54) that there is a problem when converting many-to-many relationship from a relational database and they say it loses semantic, I need more explanation about it.

Comment: And I don't understand what you're asking. Please show the source of the statement. Please provide an example.

Comment: And please understand, RDF has only binary relations. N-ary relations have to be modelled by some intermediate node (could be a blank node or a URI)

Comment: I have watched the video (Relational Database to RDF (RDB2RDF)) from Euclid.this is the link https://vimeo.com/66718408

Answer (score 1):

> ...there is a problem when converting many-to-many relationship from a relational database

I'd say that direct mapping introduces additional "parasitic" semantics, treating normalization artefacts as first-class object.

Let's consider the [D011-M2MRelations](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-rdb2rdf-test-cases-20120814/#D011-M2MRelations) testcase.

```
Student
+---------+-----------+----------+
| ID (PK) | FirstName | LastName |
+---------+-----------+----------+
| 10      | Venus     | Williams |
| 11      | Fernando  | Alonso   |
| 12      | David     | Villa    |
+---------+-----------+----------+

Student_Sport
+------------+----------+
| ID_Student | ID_Sport |
+------------+----------+
| 10         | 110      |
| 11         | 111      |
| 11         | 112      |
| 12         | 111      |
+------------+----------+

Sport
+---------+-------------+
| ID (PK) | Description |
+---------+-------------+
| 110     | Tennis      |
| 111     | Football    |
| 112     | Formula1    |
+---------+-------------+
```

Direct mapping generates a lot of triples of this kind:

```
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=111> <Student_Sport#ref-ID_Student> <Student/ID=11>.
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=111> <Student_Sport#ref-ID_Sport>  <Sport/ID=111>.
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=112> <Student_Sport#ref-ID_Student> <Student/ID=11>.
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=112> <Student_Sport#ref-ID_Sport>  <Sport/ID=112>.
```

Modeling from scratch, you'd probably write something like this (R2RML allows to achieve that):

```
<http://example.com/student/11> <http://example.com/plays> <http://example.com/sport/111>.
<http://example.com/student/11> <http://example.com/plays> <http://example.com/sport/112>.
```

Moreover, one can't improve results denormalizing original tables or creating SQL views: without primary keys, results are probably even [worse](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdb-direct-mapping/#no-pk).

In order to improve results, subsequent `DELETE/INSERT` (or `CONSTRUCT`) seems to be the only option available. The process should be named ELT rather than ETL. Perhaps the following DM-generated triples [were intended](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/track/issues/65) to help in such transformation:

```
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=111> <Student_Sport#ID_Student> "11"^^xsd:integer.
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=111> <Student_Sport#ID_Sport>  "111"^^xsd:integer.
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=112> <Student_Sport#ID_Student> "11"^^xsd:integer.
<Student_Sport/ID_Student=11;ID_Sport=112> <Student_Sport#ID_Sport>  "112"^^xsd:integer.
```

> ...they say it loses semantics

@JuanSequeda means that DM doesn't generate an OWL ontology from an relational schema, this behaviour is not many-to-many relations specific.

---

See also links from [Issue 14](https://www.w3.org/2001/sw/rdb2rdf/track/issues/14).